# How to programatically update group policy with C++?

Tags: c++, windows, active-directory, group-policy

I am managing group policies programmatically, but I am not able to find any function which updates group policy programmatically.

i.e. gpupdate /force

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me if there is no such API; group policy is fairly high-level.  You may have no choice but to resort to launching `gpupdate.exe` as a subprocess.

Comment: Looks like `gpupdate` uses an undocumented API function, ForceSyncFgPolicy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer,

IGroupPolicyObject - Windows API to create/update policies programmatically.

I would recommend you to go through this links, they will explain in deep about accessing Group Policies programmatically.

[Working with Group Policy Objects Programmatically](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsadsi/archive/2009/07/23/working-with-group-policy-objects-programmatically-simple-c-example-illustrating-how-to-modify-a-registry-based-policy.aspx)

[Programmatically updating local policy in Windows](http://www.lshift.net/blog/2013/03/25/programmatically-updating-local-policy-in-windows/)

If you have any other query, do ask.